# Facebook Ads Insights API System user and data fetching automation

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I'm going to use Facebook Ads Insights API to fetch stats about campaigns (read_insights permission) and load them into my app.

I don't want the user of my app to need to login through facebook. However, it appears that the process of getting System user is rather complicated, and even requires to produce a screencast of the user logging in (which is exactly what I don't want to implement).

Do I really need to go through all these steps to get basic/standard API access levels?
Is this the only way of generating a System user? Or of automating campaign stat fetching?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have access to all the accounts you'll be using in your app:

1. [Create a Business](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1612355968988019)
2. Add the ad accounts to your Business
3. Add your app to your Business
4. Now you can create a System User in Business Settings. Assign the assets to the System User and create an access token through the GUI. Done!

If you want access to arbitrary accounts, you'll need to create a login flow and submit for approval.